# How do I update the StatusBar Style as part of a custom transition

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm using the iOS 7 `UIviewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol to present a modal `ViewController` with a custom animation.  The animation works correctly, however, I want the newly presented `ViewController` to have a different status bar style than the presenting VC.

What I'm seeing is that `-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` gets called on the PRESENTING `ViewController` (several times in fact) and never on the newly presented `ViewController`.  If I remove the custom animation everything with the status bar works as I'd expect.

Is there something special I need to do in my animateTransition function to update the root view controller or something?  I've tried manually setting the statusBar with `[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle` but it doesn't work (I think because I'm using the ios 7 view controller based status bar styling).

This is my code for animateTransition:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UICollectionViewCell *activeCell;
    if ([self.collectionView.visibleCells containsObject:self.cellForActiveIdeaVC]) {
        activeCell = self.cellForActiveIdeaVC;
    }

    UIView *container = transitionContext.containerView;
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *fromView = fromVC.view;
    UIView *toView = toVC.view;

    CGRect beginFrame;
    if (activeCell) {
        beginFrame = [container convertRect:activeCell.bounds fromView:activeCell];
    } else {
        beginFrame = CGRectMake(container.width / 2, container.height / 2, 0, 0);
    }

    CGRect endFrame = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromVC];

    UIView *move = nil;
    if (toVC.isBeingPresented) {
        toView.frame = endFrame;
        move = [toView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
        move.frame = beginFrame;
    } else {
        if (activeCell) {
            move = [activeCell snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
        } else {
            move = [fromView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
        }
        move.frame = fromView.frame;
        [fromView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [container addSubview:move];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:700
          initialSpringVelocity:15
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         move.frame = toVC.isBeingPresented ?  endFrame : beginFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [move removeFromSuperview];

                         if (toVC.isBeingPresented) {
                             toView.frame = endFrame;
                             [container addSubview:toView];
                         } else {
                             if (self.cellForActiveIdeaVC) {
                                 self.cellForActiveIdeaVC = nil;
                             }
                         }

                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
}
```

Any pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With iOS 7 custom transitions, it's possible to present a view controller that isn't fullscreen and therefore wouldn't affect the statusbar appearance. You have to explicitly tell iOS that your custom presented view controller will, in fact, control the status bar's appearance.

```
UIViewController *controllerToPresent = [...]
controllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyleCustom;
controllerToPresent.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = YES;

[self presentViewController:controllerToPresent animated:YES completion:nil];
```

There's some [more information here](http://lxcid.com/2013/11/29/status-bar-remains-unchange-when-view-controller-is-pushed-presented-modally/). Hope that helps!

Comment: I knew it was something like this, I just couldn't find that setting.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         _preferredBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
                         [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
                     }];
```

And then you just have to return this value on the `preferredStatusBarStyle` method:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return _preferredBarStyle;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle / preferredStatusBarStyle are not getting called on my top most view controller for some reason.  It keeps asking the presenting view controller, not the new modally presented one that appears on top.

Comment: (And as I said if I remove the custom animation it works properly, so I believe I've implemented those methods properly -- its something with the custom animation)