# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning with UIStatusBarAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uistatusbar

i implemented the method in ViewController A

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return NO;
}
```

i implemented the method in ViewController B

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}

- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
  return UIStatusBarAnimationSlide; // when doing hiding animation i want it to slide up
}
```

i implemented a class `T` that conforms  for viewController transitioning say  `AtoBTransition`, i used this ViewControllerTransition for Transitioning From vc(viewcontroller) A to vc B. `when transitioning to vc B i want the status bar to slide up (hide with sliding animation)` but in this case, it seems that it doesn't do that the sliding animation.

Questions: Just Assume that i didn't do UIStatusBar related code in class `T`, and didn't add the value `View controller-based status bar appearance` in info plist. And transition `T` works perfectly as needed.

1. i'm sure the code reads in `-preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation` by doing breakpoint or logging but why it didn't hiding statusbar animation by sliding? when i toggle to slowmotion in simulator. it appears it doesn't do animation.
2. my theory is that it conflicts with transition animation context, so is it possible to do animation of hiding UIStatusBar within the implementation of `T` as part of its transition scheme?
3. is it possible to do UIStatusBar animation along with ViewControllerAnimationTransition?

feel free to clear some stuff. thanks ahead.. :)

Comment: Does your custom view controller transition (from A to B) work correctly?

Comment: Yes sir. it works correctly

Comment: Are you able to get the status bar to hide at all? I think this is what you're saying in question number 1, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Do you call `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` in the view controller B?

Comment: Yes sir. but it didn't help. there's still no status bar animation happened

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329498/how-do-i-update-the-statusbar-style-as-part-of-a-custom-transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly with iOS 7 's view controller transition API.

Now, I'm assuming based on the hooks to this API and the status bar API that the status bar is an animal unto itself and is not available for animating with a custom transition. I think this is the case because when the `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` transitionContext is created for you view controller A is already added to it's `containerView` and because you're responsible for adding view controller B to the `containerView` (because you need to transition to it) all of view controller B's status bar manipulation methods are fired when you do so.

However, you **can** animate `UIApplication`'s `keyWindow`'s frame during your animation transition So in the `-animateTransition:` method of your class that implements `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);  // move frame up

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    // assuming 
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 568); //move frame down
}];
```

If you go with this approach, you'll probably need to adjust the frame of the key window in view controller A to drop below the status bar and be styled light/dark as needed. Then do the opposite to get the effect you want in view controller B. Its nasty, but it could work.

Comment: Sir, is it also the same case if we push view controller to navigationController? it still has animation transition (default) right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: i mean pushing view to navigationController with `self.navigationController pushViewController`also has transition. is it the same case as above? because i cant do animation of statusbar hiding even when i transition from `A` to `B` without `T`. without using `T` on Transition `A` to `B`.